get panda column or else defaults
In cases where one can't assume a data-frame's column exists, I often find myself implementing a "maybe get column else fill with default values" approach. Wondering if there is a more Pandas Idiomatic style than this?
df.get("column", default=pd.Series([dfl_value] * df.shape[0]))


What's the context? I can think of at least one where you could just use a scalar instead.

Yea df.get(“missing_column”) returns a single scalar value rather than the intended vector. The context is for processing different sources (or versions) of data in a production system in the same way without having downstream logic care which input columns are optional or missing.

Oh sorry, I meant what are you doing with the result?

These data frames eventually feed several ML algorithms which expect certain columns to exist. But that’s beyond scope of this question

I mean, what are you immediately doing with the Series after the .get? The situation I had in mind was using it on other columns in the same df, like say df['column'] + df['other column'].

Right. The immediate logic is to normalize the column from itself or from other columns in the data frame.
df[’col’] = df.get(’col’, default).apply(norm_fn).astype(my_type) or
df[‘col’] = df.get(‘col1’, default1) + df.get(‘col2’, default2)

You could reindex:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})

df.reindex(columns=['col'], fill_value=999)

Or for a Series:
df.reindex(columns=['col'], fill_value=999).squeeze()

Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})

df.reindex(columns=['col'], fill_value=999).squeeze()

# 0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
# Name: col, dtype: int64

df.reindex(columns=['col2'], fill_value=999).squeeze()

# 0    999
# 1    999
# 2    999
# Name: col2, dtype: int64

You could also create a custom pandas method:
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def get_col(df, col, default=None):
    if col in df:
        return df.get(col)
    return pd.Series([default]*len(df),
                     index=df.index,
                     name=col,
                    )

PandasObject.get_col = get_col

NB. using try/except to avoid building the default Series if it's not needed.
Then use get_col:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})

df.get_col('col', default=999)

# 0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
# Name: col, dtype: int64

df.get_col('col2', default=999)

# 0    999
# 1    999
# 2    999
# Name: col2, dtype: int64

